# Espresso - get text of element

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

If I have an "AppCompatTextView" element that I can access by:

```
onView(withId(R.id.allergies_text))
```

From Layout Inspector:

[image]

Is there a way I can access the text of the element in Android Studio? (to access whatever text is there... not check if some text exists in the element)

I tried to do:

```
val tv = onView(withId(R.id.medical_summary_text_view)) as TextView
val text = text.text.toString()
print(text)
```

But I get the error:

*android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a matcher to access to that element value.

For instance, you can check if it's text has some value:

```
Matcher<View> hasValueEqualTo(final String content) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Has EditText/TextView the value:  " + content);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view instanceof TextView) && !(view instanceof EditText)) {
                    return false;
            }
            if (view != null) {
                String text;
                if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    text = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                } else {
                    text = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
                }

                return (text.equalsIgnoreCase(content));
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

And call it this way:

```
onView(withId(R.id.medical_summary_text_view))
    .check(matches(hasValueEqualTo(value)));
```

or you can edit this matcher to return just whether the text is empty or not:

```
Matcher<View> textViewHasValue() {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("The TextView/EditText has value");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view instanceof TextView) && !(view instanceof EditText)) {
                    return false;
            }
            if (view != null) {
                String text;
                if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    text = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                } else {
                    text = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
                }

                return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text));
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

And call it this way:

```
onView(withId(R.id.medical_summary_text_view))
    .check(matches(textViewHasValue()));
```

Comment: Great example of a custom matcher. Thanks

Comment: Although this is generally how espresso testing works, it doesn't answer the user's question.  He wants to find out what text is actually on the element that he's matched, not check it against a known quantity.

Comment: But testing consists in checking if the state and the values of your app match what you expect. For me, getting the value is debugging an app, not testing it. What is important in every test is to check whether the condition you expect is happening

Answer (score 5):

You can get the text of the `ViewInteraction` by the following function:

```
fun getText(matcher: ViewInteraction): String {
    var text = String()
    matcher.perform(object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java)
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Text of the view"
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            val tv = view as TextView
            text = tv.text.toString()
        }
    })

    return text
}
```

```
val numberResult: ViewInteraction = onView(withId(R.id.txNumberResult))
var searchText = getText(numberResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and this is what ended up working for me:

if you have an activity rule

```
var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)
```

then you can do something like this:

```
activityRule.launchActivity(null)
val textView: TextView = activityRule.activity.findViewById(R.id.some_text_view)
val text = textView.text
```

I think this may be more along the lines of what the original poster was looking for.

Comment: I tried your example and I'm getting exception: `IllegalStateException: searchActivity.activity.…ewById(R.id.recipe_title) must not be null` I was not able get text this way

Answer (score 0):

When you really want to have the text and not only match it with another value or empty, I post the full final working solution in Java (Not Kotlin) based on the algoritghm of @Mesut GUNES

```
public class TextHelpers {
public static String getText(ViewInteraction matcher){
    final String[] text = new String[1];
    ViewAction va = new ViewAction() {

        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription(){
            return "Text of the view";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController,View view) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            text[0] = tv.getText().toString();
        }
    };

    matcher.perform(va);

    return text[0];
}
```

}

So, in your test you can call it like that:

```
TextHelpers.getText(Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.element)));
```

It works for all controls extending TextView, so it does on EditText too.